# Permission Denied error in make

Tags: 14.04, make

I'm trying to build the [macchina.io](https://github.com/macchina-io/macchina.io). When I run the command

```
make -s -j8 DEFAULT_TARGET=shared_release
```

it gives me the error of permission denied.

[image]

Comment: I think you're using an NTFS partition. `make` is attempting to run `script/makedepend.gcc`, but can't since it isn't executable.

Comment: @muru You are right, I am using NTFS partition. Whats the solution for this?

Comment: You'll have to mount it yourself with the correct settings. See the linked post.